# Counting the String letters

Tags: java, arrays, string

The program needs to count the number of "O" and "P" that you input. It will output the number of "O" and the number of "P" and if you input X the program will terminate then it will output if it is equal or not equal with the use of an array. Can someone give me the code or algorithm of this?

Here's my code

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{

    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=0;
    String input;
    String a[] = { "A", "a"};
    String b[] = { "B", "b"};        

    while(x==0)
    {
        input=scn.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("X")||input.equals("x"))
        {
            System.out.println("Terminated");
            break;
        }
        //what to do next?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your code already looks up matching an  X, now all you need is a way to detect A and B in a similar fashion and a variable in as the count of A and B. Then add the print out to the print statements in the area of your code which is the termination if clause

Comment: As you want to count, you need `count`

Comment: The whole point of homework is for you to do it, not us. Trust me that it will save you the disappointment later when no one will hire you because you can't actually write code.

Comment: `class _{public static void main(String[]_)throws Throwable{int i=0,c;while((c=System.in.read())!=88)i+=c==79||c==80?1:0;System.out.printf("%s",i);}}`  Here you go :-)

Answer (score 2):

seems like a homework so just giving a hints.

- you are checking the letter x for terminating. there in another two
  if statement check if the character is p or 0.
- declare two variable to count the number of P and O.
- if the character is P then increment the variable for P. do same for
  O.

Comment: BTW another hint , instead of using input.equals("X")||input.equals("x"), you can use equalsIgnoreCase() method. Prevents unncesary code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
  Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
  int x=0;
  int countO=0;
  int countP=0;
  String input;
  String a[] = { "A", "a"};
  String b[] = { "B", "b"};        

  while(x==0)
  {
    input=scn.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("X")||input.equals("x"))
    {
        System.out.println("Terminated");
        System.out.println("number of O = " + countO);
        System.out.println("number of P = " + countP);
        break;
    }
  // In the same way as you check for X check input for O then P
  // If it is O then increase the count for O.
  //If it is P then increase the count for P.
}
```